# Ajax and Access Control

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

have a project I'm working on and I'm trying to pull from a Google API. (It does not have a JSONP option).

Right now, I'm getting a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" error. I've added the following php:

```
<?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');

 ?>
```

And here is my Ajax call:

```
$.getJSON(path,function(data) {
                console.log(typeof(data));
            });
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Given you're using PHP anyway, I would use jQuery to make an ajax call to a PHP page on *your* server, then have that PHP page call the Google API and return the results back to the browser. That way you don't have to worry about same-origin issues.

Comment: adding those headers in your php won't have any effect on a call the browser makes to another domain